# Python Regex Matching First and Last Characters

Tags: python, regex

A note of caution: avoid reading my string here, I will bold the interesting parts, I know it is a mess.

I am trying to find all substrings in

> "jashdgfkldsuvha sjdgjhayaluiegfasdgfguiasdgo"

which start with the character "a" and end with the character "l" (that is a lowercase L). Specifically, I want a non-greedy search.

If I run

```
re.findall("(a.*?l)", "jashdgfkldsuvha sjdgjhayaluiegfasdgfguiasdgo")
```

it returns:

```
['ashdgfkl', 'a sjdgjhayal']
```

but notice in the string we have the letters "al" in order:

> "jashdgfkldsuvha sjdgjhay**al**uiegfasdgfguiasdgo"

I'm not an expert at regex, so I assumed that maybe, even though * should allow for a match of zero characters, that the match of zero here wasn't working. So let's add some characters between this "al" to get

> "jashdgfkldsuvha sjdgjhay**ajkdl**uiegfasdgfguiasdgo"

but it still only returns

```
['ashdgfkl', 'a sjdgjhayajkdl']
```

What is going on here? Why does regex have a vendetta against this particular "a" and "l"?

Comment: You could try `re.findall("(?=(a.*?l))", "jashdgfkldsuvha sjdgjhayaluiegfasdgfguiasdgo")` which returns `['ashdgfkl', 'a sjdgjhayal', 'ayal', 'al']`

Comment: Or you can use the `regex` module which does support overlapping matches. Both cases are covered in the duplicate.